# How to detect touch event at ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, ontouchlistener

**Before explaining, I don't want to use TouchEvent at Scrollview inner Scrollview.**

I want to make when touching up the scrollView, make popup window. but to use onTouchEvent, isn't it only can detect ACTION_MOVE, UP, DOWN?

I used gesture detector.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);

        ScrollView readScroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.readScrollView);
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView);
        String filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("File_Path");

        textView.setText(readFile(filePath));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        Toast.makeText(ReadActivity.this, "onKeyUp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
```

but it doesn't work.
I think it is disabled because of scrollView.

How to detect touch event at scrollView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already mentioned in the question, `onTouchEvent` do have `ACTION_UP` that is meant to [handle when touch up](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to observe if scroll is moving up or down.

Firstly checkout [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener.html)

Implementation:

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

    }
});
```

If you are checking if it up or down motion just simply compare **scrollX** and **oldScrollX**, horizontally **scrollY** and **oldscrollY**

Comment: Nope.. Observe touchEvent in ScrollView. Thanks!